# Is it valid in inheritance (semantically) to have a restriction that prevents cross-implementation uses?

Tags: interface, liskov-substitution-principle

Imagine a scenario where you want to create some ranking system, where the underlying ranking implementations are to be flexible.

There might be some ranking function, which takes in an `IRanker` and run that as needed on provisioned resources.

```
interface IRanker
{
    double Rank(MyDataItem item);
}

List<double> RunRankingSystem(List<MyDataItem> items, IRanker ranker);
```

However, given the flexibility for each `IRanker` implementation, it can be that these are not comparable. For example one Ranker may return values in [0, 1], while another may be [0, inf). That is, the results are not comparable across two arbitrary IRanker instances where the concrete types are not known, but for one IRanker instance, the results can be compared.

From an academic standpoint, I'm wondering whether this subtly breaks some of the requirements of true inheritance, akin to LSP for example, or is violation of some other principle. I am looking specifically for some more concrete underpinning as justification.

I already know that there are some usability issues with such a design as this requirement is not enforced or obvious, but my question is whether a contract forbidding the comparisons of these results is a violation of something else, not just whether the contract choice is a good one.

Comment: It does not as long as you do not specify anything about the return value at the level of `IRanker`. You can specify that `IRanker` can only return values within [0, 1] and then any implementation not returning that will violate the LSP.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment. I'm looking to not have any requirements on the return value of IRanker except that it be in the range [0, inf). Some rankers may have an algorithm that returns a result from [0, 1]. But the results of two IRankers cannot be compared unless they are from the exact same instance.

Comment: Responding to your comment though, I do realize that I wrote basically what you said but with different ranges (and which I didn't clarify in the original question). So the design should be fine in regards to LSP. But I still feel like something is off, but perhaps it's just that returning double from the Rank function sort of distorts the implicit domain.

If a tagged double type was returned, associated with the specific Ranker instance, that would make things more clear (although not really possible implementation wise in most languages)

Comment: It actually depends what you mean to "compare". Do you mean we're going to compare the goodness of two things but the ranks of them are given by different ranking algorithms? That does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: No, specifically that is what is not allowed. The question is, in disallowing that in this class structure, does that violate anything?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you meant now, I kind of misunderstood your question before. My opinion is that it is just hard to enforce this kind of constraint and they bring more trouble than good in weaker type systems (like Java). It is better to abide the rule yourself and ensure you use the same `IRanker` instance all the time.